# Firebase Crash Reporting not working

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting, run-script

I have setup firebase crash reporting in my iOS app. I have downloaded the `ServiceAccount.json` and `GoogleService-Info.plist` and are included in my project's target.

Here is the build script:

```
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:*********:ios:************
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}"/ServiceAccount.json
```

Path to json file is correct as it's in root directory of my project. But when I archive the app, it gives an error during compile time in file - `upload-sym-util.bash` at this line during verification of plist file.

```
if ! fcr_verify_svc_plist; then
    xcerror "Incorrect/incomplete service account file."
    return 2
```

I have tried changing the build script but no gain.

Here is the snippet from my Podfile.lock:

```
- Firebase/Crash (4.5.0):
- Firebase/Core
- FirebaseCrash (= 2.0.2)
```

What could be the issue as I have followed the steps mentioned in the integration guide for crash reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted it out. The provided ServiceAccount.json file had no private key in it.

It was some other json from Firebase console. So its good to check the contents of json file when this issue occurs:

```
if ! fcr_verify_svc_plist; then
xcerror "Incorrect/incomplete service account file."
return 2
```

Thanks,